# Unable to update the UI using the message from the handler

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-handler

*Hello everyone, I am new to android application development. I have written and code and trying to update the UI from the message obtained from handler. I have tried to debug the code but i couldn't find what the error is. please help me out. Thank you.*

```
    package com.threadcommunicationexample;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button Click;
    TextView Message;
    Handler Mrmessenger;
    int Counter = 0;

    /*
     *Initialisation area.... 
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClickButton);
    Message = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    Click.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // Operation to be performed after the button click 

    Runnable myThreadRunner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        // Saving the text in bundle and passing it to handler .... 

            while (Counter < 100) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    Message msg = Mrmessenger.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
                    myBundle.putString("Communication", "Loading....");
                    msg.setData(myBundle);

                //Sending the bundle to Handler 

                    Mrmessenger.sendMessage(msg);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Mrmessenger = new Handler() {

                    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {

                        Mrmessenger.post(new Runnable() {
     // Getting the message from the handler and updating it using textview

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Bundle ComBundle = msg.getData();
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                String myMessage = ComBundle
                                        .getString("Communication");
                                Message.setText(myMessage);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                };
                Counter++;
            }

        }

    };

    Thread myRunner = new Thread(myThreadRunner); 
    //creating a thread and passing the runnable object.
    myRunner.start();

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the line
`Message msg = Mrmessenger.obtainMessage();`
will fail since you don't initialize `Mrmessenger` until a few lines later.

Would recommend you use `AsyncTask` for this type of thing; it deals with all of the threading so you don't have to.

Also: per Java conventions, variable names should start with a lowercase letter, class names start with an uppercase letter.  This would make your code easier for others to read.

Comment: Actually I am practicing and learning the concept of thread and inter thread communication..as a part of that i am trying out examples like these ....

Comment: Yes that was the error i have initialised it some where and I was calling it before........i have corrected it and .it worked..!!!! Thanks Bohica ...

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is, that the run method in your handler is called on another thread than the main / ui thread.
To make the code working you can use the following code..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Message.setText(myMessage);
    }
});
```

..to run the ui update explicitly on the ui thread.

Comment: Actually there is a silly mistake in the program in the initialization section ...i was trying to typecast the text View as button ..... i have corrected that  and also ...i have edited the code as you said replacing it with runon Ui method but still it crashes...

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your crash.